# SIMD vs OMP in vector multiplication

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, openmp, avx

In my project I have to do several vector multiplications, done on either `double *a`-vectors or `float *a`-vectors. In order to accelerate that, I wanted to use either SIMD-operations or `omp`. For getting the fastest result, I wrote a benchmark program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>


#define SIZE 32768
#define ROUNDS 1e5

void multiply_singular(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        d[i] = a[i]*b[i];
}

void multiply_omp(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        d[i] = a[i]*b[i];
}

void multiply_avx(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
    __m256 a_a, b_a, c_a;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE/8; i++)
    {
        a_a = _mm256_loadu_ps(a+8*i);
        b_a = _mm256_loadu_ps(b+8*i);
        c_a = _mm256_mul_ps(a_a, b_a);
        _mm256_storeu_ps (d+i*8, c_a);
    }
}

void multiply_avx_omp(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
    __m256 a_a, b_a, c_a;
#pragma omp for
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE/8; i++)
    {
        a_a = _mm256_loadu_ps(a+8*i);
        b_a = _mm256_loadu_ps(b+8*i);
        c_a = _mm256_mul_ps(a_a, b_a);
        _mm256_storeu_ps (d+i*8, c_a);
    }
}

void multiply_singular_double(double *a, double *b, double *d)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        d[i] = a[i]*b[i];
}

void multiply_omp_double(double *a, double *b, double *d)
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        d[i] = a[i]*b[i];
}

void multiply_avx_double(double *a, double *b, double *d)
{
    __m256d a_a, b_a, c_a;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE/4; i++)
    {
        a_a = _mm256_loadu_pd(a+4*i);
        b_a = _mm256_loadu_pd(b+4*i);
        c_a = _mm256_mul_pd(a_a, b_a);
        _mm256_storeu_pd (d+i*4, c_a);
    }
}

void multiply_avx_double_omp(double *a, double *b, double *d)
{
    __m256d a_a, b_a, c_a;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE/4; i++)
    {
        a_a = _mm256_loadu_pd(a+4*i);
        b_a = _mm256_loadu_pd(b+4*i);
        c_a = _mm256_mul_pd(a_a, b_a);
        _mm256_storeu_pd (d+i*4, c_a);
    }
}


int main()
{
    float *a, *b, *c, *d, *e, *f;
    double *a_d, *b_d, *c_d, *d_d, *e_d, *f_d;
    a = new float[SIZE] {0};
    b = new float[SIZE] {0};
    c = new float[SIZE] {0};
    d = new float[SIZE] {0};
    e = new float[SIZE] {0};
    f = new float[SIZE] {0};
    a_d = new double[SIZE] {0};
    b_d = new double[SIZE] {0};
    c_d = new double[SIZE] {0};
    d_d = new double[SIZE] {0};
    e_d = new double[SIZE] {0};
    f_d = new double[SIZE] {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
        a_d[i] = i;
        b_d[i] = i;
    };
    std::cout << "Now doing the single float rounds!\n";
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        multiply_singular(a, b, c);
    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_ss = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the omp float rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS*10; i++)
    {
        multiply_omp(a, b, d);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_so = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the avx float rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS*10; i++)
    {
        multiply_avx(a, b, e);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_sa = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the avx omp float rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS*10; i++)
    {
        multiply_avx_omp(a, b, e);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_sao = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the single double rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i++)
    {
        multiply_singular_double(a_d, b_d, c_d);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_ds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the omp double rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS*10; i++)
    {
        multiply_omp_double(a_d, b_d, d_d);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_do = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the avx double rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS*10; i++)
    {
        multiply_avx_double(a_d, b_d, e_d);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_da = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Now doing the avx omp double rounds!\n";
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for(int i = 0; i < ROUNDS*10; i++)
    {
        multiply_avx_double_omp(a_d, b_d, f_d);
    };
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_dao = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    std::cout << "Finished\n";
    std::cout << "Elapsed time for functions:\n";
    std::cout << "Function\ttime[ms]\n";
    std::cout << "Singular float:\t" << duration_ss/ROUNDS << '\n';
    std::cout << "OMP float:\t" << duration_so/(ROUNDS*10) << '\n';
    std::cout << "AVX float avx:\t" << duration_sa/(ROUNDS*10) << '\n';
    std::cout << "OMP AVX float avx omp:\t" << duration_sao/(ROUNDS*10) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Singular double:\t" << duration_ds/ROUNDS << '\n';
    std::cout << "OMP double:\t" << duration_do/(ROUNDS*10) << '\n';
    std::cout << "AVX double:\t" << duration_da/(ROUNDS*10) << '\n';
    std::cout << "OMP AVX double:\t" << duration_dao/(ROUNDS*10) << '\n';
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
    delete[] d;
    delete[] e;
    delete[] f;
    delete[] a_d;
    delete[] b_d;
    delete[] c_d;
    delete[] d_d;
    delete[] e_d;
    delete[] f_d;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it with `g++-5 -fopenmp -std=c++14 -march=native test_new.cpp -o test -lgomp`, I get

```
Elapsed time for functions:
Function    time[ms]
Singular float: 117.979
OMP float:  40.5385
AVX float avx:  60.2964
OMP AVX float avx omp:  61.4206
Singular double:    129.59
OMP double: 200.745
AVX double: 136.715
OMP AVX double: 122.176
```

or in a second run

```
Elapsed time for functions:
Function    time[ms]
Singular float: 113.932
OMP float:  39.2581
AVX float avx:  58.3029
OMP AVX float avx omp:  60.0023
Singular double:    123.575
OMP double: 66.0327
AVX double: 124.293
OMP AVX double: 318.038
```

Here obviously the pure `omp`-function is faster than the other functions, even as the AVX function. When adding the `-O3`-switch to the compiling line, I get the following result:

```
Elapsed time for functions:
Function    time[ms]
Singular float: 12.7361
OMP float:  4.82436
AVX float avx:  14.7514
OMP AVX float avx omp:  14.7225
Singular double:    27.9976
OMP double: 8.50957
AVX double: 32.5175
OMP AVX double: 257.219
```

Here again `omp` is significantly faster than everything else, while AVX is slowest, even slower than the linear approach. Why is that? Is my AVX function implementation just crappy, or are there other problems?

Executed on Ubuntu 14.04.1, i7 Sandy Bridge, gcc version 5.3.0.

Edit: I found one mistake: I should move the declarations of the temporary variables in the `avx`-functions inside the for-loop, that gets me nearly to the `omp`-level (and delivers correct results).

Edit 2: When disabling the `-O3`-switch, the `OMP`-`AVX`-instructions are faster than the `OMP`-functions, with the switch they are nearly on par.

Edit 3: When filling the arrays with random data every time before executing the next loop, I get (with `-O3`):

```
Elapsed time for functions:
Function    time[ms]
Singular float: 30.742
Cilk float: 24.0769
OMP float:  17.2415
AVX float avx:  33.0217
OMP AVX float avx omp:  10.1934
Singular double:    60.412
Cilk double:    34.6458
OMP double: 19.0739
AVX double: 66.8676
OMP AVX double: 22.3586
```

and without:

```
Elapsed time for functions:
Function    time[ms]
Singular float: 274.402
Cilk float: 88.258
OMP float:  66.2124
AVX float avx:  117.066
OMP AVX float avx omp:  35.0313
Singular double:    238.652
Cilk double:    91.1667
OMP double: 127.621
AVX double: 249.516
OMP AVX double: 116.24
```

(and I added a cilk_for()-loop for comparison, too).

Update: 
I added (as suggested in the answer) also a function using the `#pragma omp parallel for simd`.
That resulted in:

```
Elapsed time for functions:
Function                time[ms]
Singular float:         106.081
Cilk float:             33.2761
OMP float:              17.0651
AVX float avx:          65.1129
OMP AVX float:          19.1496
SIMD OMP float:         2.6095
Aligned AVX OMP float:  18.1165
Singular double:        118.939
Cilk double:            53.1102
OMP double:             35.652
AVX double:             131.24
OMP AVX double:         39.4377
SIMD OMP double:        7.0748
Aligned AVX OMP double: 38.4474
```

Comment: Alignment of data can affect speed. malloc()/new() is not guaranteed to give you the needed alignment.

Comment: ...in practice you're forced to use `_mm256_loadu`_pd which is **MUCH** slower than `_mm256_load_pd` (and complementary store instruction). Where you declare temporary variables _should_ not affect performance (inspecting generated assembly you _should_ see exactly same code, at least I expect you do...lol). Try using `_aligned_malloc` and re-run your tests

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Do you have a reference for that ? Last time I checked, the difference is insignificant on any modern CPU.

Comment: Something is not right here. I'm a little surprised the compiler hasn't just optimised away the first method, but at `O3` it should at-least have done the vectorisation itself. Can you look at what *was* auto vectorised with `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose`? Also this is not a good benchmark; cache locality will likely play a dominant role here (try reordering the tests), and you are using non-random data.

Comment: @ElderBug just my own tests on something similar but targeted CPUs were more than few (and not only modern ones) then you may be right, for newer CPUs difference may be negligible (didn't measure, so far)

Comment: @Daniel: I get nothing from the compiler when adding the switch. I updated my code with randomized data, and added the results above.

Comment: @arc_lupus It's a level not a switch, I believe setting it to 2 should be fine, but you could also read the documentation.

Comment: @Daniel: It does not change, regardless of the value (tested 0, 2, 3, 5). Still no output from the compiler

Comment: Your timing methods have a couple of problems: (i) don't send anything to stdout until you're done timing (i.e. get rid of the "Now doing ..." messages); (ii) you need to make sure that all your memory allocations (and code) are wired, in order to avoid page faults (easiest method is to just run each test once prior to the timing loop).

Comment: @PaulR: Why should I get rid of the std::cout-messages, if they are outside of the timing loops?

Comment: @arc_lupus: well, assuming you're using a GUI, with some sort of terminal window, every `cout` generates updates to the screen, which happen asynchronously and can overlap the following timing loop. For best timing results you really don't want any other CPU activity, so no desktop animations, screen savers, window updates, etc. Better still, shut down the GUI altogether, and drive everything via an ssh connection.

Comment: @PaulR: Makes sense, thanks for learning something new!

Comment: @Daniel: gcc enables auto-vectorization by default at `-O3`, but not at `-O2`.  (clang does at `-O2`).  @ arc:  OpenMP has SIMD directives:  `#pragma omp simd`.  It requests autovectorization, and allows associative-math for that loop so reductions can be vectorized, etc.  Can you use both?

Comment: @PeterCordes, I was not aware Clang used auto-vectorization at `-O2`. That's good to know.

Comment: Your problem is that `__m256 a_a, b_a, c_a` and `__m256d a_a, b_a, c_a` are shared. They should be private.

Comment: Oh I see you found that in a comment " found one mistake: I should move the declarations of the temporary variables in the avx-functions inside the for-loop".  Yeah, that makes them private.

Comment: Your last result with `simd` does not make sense. What optimization did you compile with?

Comment: As listed above, including `-O3`. Why?

Comment: Makes no sense.  You did state you used `-O3` with your `simd` update.  With your last update Singular float took `106.081`. But above that with `-O3` it only took `30.742 ` but without `-O3` before the update it took `274.402`. The values from your last update are not consistent with your previous results.

Comment: Reason for that might be because I changed the array size while testing, but never changed it back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With compilers supporting OpenMP**4.x** you may want to start from something like this:

```
void multiply_singular_omp_for_simd(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for simd schedule (static,16)
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        d[i] = a[i]*b[i];
}
```

It will give you both SIMD and Thread parallelism. The parallel decomposition will be done automatically, first having parallel tasks/chunks spread across threads/cores, secondly for every task/chunk spreading individual iterations "across" simd "lanes".

Read given couple articles if you feel concerned: 
[Threading and SIMD in OpenMP4](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/enabling-simd-in-program-using-openmp40), [ICC documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524527).

Formally the way you phrased your question is slightly ambiguous, because staring from 4.0, OMP loop could be SIMD, Threading or SIMD+Threading parallel. So it's not about OMP vs. SIMD anymore. Instead it's about OMP SIMD vs. OMP Threading.

Not sure how good your given GCC implementation is, but ICC/IFORT can deal with omp parallel for simd for relatively long time now. GCC should also support it starting from 5.x (#pragma omp simd was supported by GCC for some time, but it's not necessary the case for #pragma omp parallel for simd).

For optimal compiler-driven implementation you may ideally prefer to do cache blocking and manually split iteration space to have outer loop driven by omp parallel for, while innermost loop driven by omp simd. But this is maybe slightly out of scope of original question.

Comment: Holy S*, that command got me a 5x-speedup compared to the fastest version before...

Comment: There is something fishy about this. `omp simd` does not do any more magic that auto-vectorization does. So this 5x-speedup with `-O3` and `simd` makes no sense. The OP should not be doing thread work sharing over the L1 Cache array size either. I don't really see a major advantage of `omp simd` that I can't get with a some compiler switches. If it unrolls the loop in dependency chains then it would be useful but it does not even do this.  From my point of few `omp simd` only adds some convenient features like `aligned` and not having to use `-Ofast` for the entire translation unit.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP implementation in GCC at all. For intel compiler I can tell you that "explicit vectorization" relaxes some language semantic limitations (so compiler is free to do "riskier" things like e.g. fp moel vs. svml libary) and therefore the performance of auto-vectorized loops could be lower than simd loops performance.

Comment: So my comment is not regarding your 1st statement about fishy 5x  vs. something else (this question may not be exactly to me), but more about your 2nd statement that there is no advantages of omp simd over auto-vectorization. I disagree with 2nd statement. These days there are very many advantages of omp simd (or more generally "explicit vectorization"), I tried to mention just one of these advantages above.